# What background do people here have? Ecology, molecular biology, neuroscience, others?

Tags: discussion

What is your level of education, and what field of biology do you know the most about?

Comment: Is this question *really* constructive? It seems that something like this belongs in chat, rather than in a meta question.

Comment: @Polynomial: Good idea. This sort of *getting-to-know-you* question is better suited for chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I studied biotechnology, now I work in computational intelligence using it from time to time to solve some bioinformatical problems.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a PhD student in Epidemiology, with some background in Microbiology.

Answer (score 3):

I've been writing software for 15 years and am currently helping my Junior Highschool and High-School aged kids with their Biology homework.

Oh, and I'm 100% biological.

Answer (score 3):

I am a PhD student in bioinformatics -- specifically RNA-seq.  I have also spent a lot of time doing wet lab work in a molecular biology lab.